# Create a website to show data from a remote XML dataset

Tags: mysql, xml, dataset, remote-access

I am currently making a data visualisation website which looks at a remote source of data which is in XML.

I am confused on how to get the data from the XML dataset into a MySQL database.

Comment: What are you confused about?

Comment: What language are you using on the website? If it's PHP, you can use `file_get_contents()` or curl to pull data from the remote source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to visualize, probably you don't need to put the data into the database. probably you just need to have the data accessible on the client side (javascript). in this case, you should just call the XML data interface from javascript (with jquery, for example), and process the result

Comment: He'll still need a proxy webserver, to get around Cross-Origin AJAX restrictions.

Comment: as far as i know, he will need your solution (proxy webserver) or a JSONP data source, or control on the data server (which i suppose is missing since he wrote *remote*). so yes, if he has just the XML format for the data (as written in the question), he will also need a proxy server

Comment: the XML data is also in JSON format, which I can access, if I do that would using json_decode php work more effiecntly than converting the data into a local database? at the moment I current have the XML data converted to XLS into CSV which is then turned into SQL then my PHP accesses the SQL database and output the data.

Comment: JSON and JSONP are different. Are you sure you need to put the data into the database? if so, i cannot help you so much. i was proposing a client side solution, were the server was just acting as a proxy. this was a little outside from your question. if you are sure to import data, maybe you could add the tag [tag:php] to the question